# object.valid? returns false but object.errors.full_messages is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, save

I'm confuse about objects that I can't save, simplified model is

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::base
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
has_many :transactions, :class_name => "SubscriptionTransaction" 

validates_presence_of :first_name, :message => "ne peut être vide"
validates_presence_of :last_name, :message => "ne peut être vide"
validates_presence_of :card_number, :message => "ne peut être vide"
validates_presence_of :card_verification, :message => "ne peut être vide"
validates_presence_of :card_type, :message => "ne peut être vide"
validates_presence_of :card_expires_on, :message => "ne peut être vide"

attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification

validate_on_create :validate_card

    def validate_card 
    unless credit_card.valid?
        credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            errors.add_to_base message
        end
    end
end

def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        :type => card_type,
        :number => card_number,
        :verification_value => card_verification,
        :month => card_expires_on.month,
        :year => card_expires_on.year,
        :first_name => first_name,
        :last_name => last_name
    )
end
end
```

and in my subscription_controller

```
if subscription.save
     # do something
else
     debugger # means breakpoint where i try subscription.errors.full_messages
     # do something else
end
```

I tried to use ruby-debug for this adding a breakpoint where i do some tests

```
subscription.valid? #=> false 
subscription.errors.full_messages #=> []
subscription.save! #=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed:)
```

which explains that ActiveRecord doesn't allow the save method. Unfortunately i can't know why the object is invalid.

If you have any idea, thank you.

Comment: Can you add your validators back in? It would also be nice to see a script/console session showing what you believe to be a valid subscription being created.

Comment: When do you call `subscription.errors.full_messages`? After `save`/`valid?`?

Comment: Thank you for answers, Mark I add my validations. Marcel I try to display errors after save missed (I added debugger breakpoint in the controller in the example)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had the same problem. At first I had such code in my model:

```
before_validation :set_some_param

def set_some_param
   self.some_param = some_value
end
```

After I changed this to:

```
before_validation :set_some_param

def set_some_param
   self.some_param = some_value
   true
end
```

I could see my errors.

Maybe you have something simular in your code?

Comment: Specifically from [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html): If the returning value of a before_validation callback can be evaluated to false, the process will be aborted and Base#save will return false. If ActiveRecord::Validations#save! is called it will raise a ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception. Nothing will be appended to the errors object.

Comment: wow, I was going crazy with this... 2 hours wasted but finally your solution worked!

Comment: I also stumbled upon this. My general solution for this problem is to just use `assign_attributes(some_param: some_value)` instead of directly assigning the attribute, because that will return a truthy value on success.

Comment: 5+ years later, this answer is still saving devs' sanity...thank you.

Comment: Yup, only 1.5 hours wasted. We should add them all up!

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you try `@object.save!`

Ruby should tell you what went wrong during the attempt to save the object.

Comment: save! generates the following exception
    
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: 

and sadly no more details

Comment: If save! throws an exception, maybe you can put a rescue block in your code and inspect the exception for a full stack trace? Or I think there are other ways to get a full stack trace, I seem to remember doing something like `@object.save! --trace` but I can't remember exactly... If nothing of that sort works, je n'ai aucune idée mon ami :(

Answer (score 6):

Try looking at the results from:

```
subscription.errors.inspect
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, as you can see we still can't see errors invalidating the object
    @subscription.errors.inspect #=>
  <... @errors={}>"

Answer (score 2):

Ok I finally found the problem, thanks mates for the help.

I was overriding the valid? method in Subscription class to test another functionality which has not the same semantic. Big mistake, I juste renamed the method and it now works like a charm.